# How to download gpx files in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Good afternoon everyone !

I have this simple code in the controller

```
    public function descargarRutaGPX($id){
        $buscar = Ruta::find($id);
        $file = Storage::get('ddfbdsfv.gpx');
        echo $file;
   }
```

If the file exists the browser show "Preppend text" , but if the file doesn't exists the browser shows **FileNotFoundException in FilesystemAdapter.php** line 61.

Could anyone help to me ?

**UPDATED**

```
 $buscar = Ruta::find($id);
        if (Storage::has('aaaa.gpx')) {
             $file = Storage::get('aaaa.gpx');
             return response()->download($file);
        }else{
            echo "NO";
        }
```

This is the error.

```
The file "Prepended Text" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to check and make sure the file exists as well as download the file if it does. Try changing your code to the following

```
public function descargarRutaGPX($id){
    $buscar = Ruta::find($id);
    If (Storage::has('ddfbdsfv.gpx') {
          $file = Storage::get('ddfbdsfv.gpx');
           return response()->download($file);
    } else {
            // file not found. Do something to alert the user
    }
}
```

Comment: Now , I can check the file but I show the same error ,